# Installing OpenCV/python on Amazon Linux (apache)?

Tags: python, apache, opencv, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use OpenCV on a python web application I created on an Amazon EC2 Micro instance running apache.

I've got everything configured and working, except OpenCV isn't installing. This is the output I got from the Apache Error Log.

```
[Thu Aug 04 18:31:54 2016] [error] [client 72.219.147.5]     import cv2
[Thu Aug 04 18:31:54 2016] [error] [client 72.219.147.5] ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Here is what I've tried:

I've installed pip and tried running `pip install pyopencv`

That doesn't work and gives me errors.

I've also tried manually installing it by following this: [How to install OpenCV on Amazon Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244606/how-to-install-opencv-on-amazon-linux)

and this: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html?highlight=download#installing-opencv-python-from-pre-built-binaries

and this: http://techieroop.com/install-opencv-in-centos/

Even after installation, the cv2.so file is nowhere to be be found. I tried to search for it using `sudo find / -name "cv2.so"` but nothing came up.

I do, however, have the following `.so` files installed:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
```

Also, when running the cmake command, this is the output I'm getting:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.10)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       NO (Python wrappers can not be generated)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you copy cv2.so to site-packages under your python distribution (e.g. /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages)?

Comment: @bblincoe where is the cv2.so file? In my /usr/local/lib/python2.6/ I don't have any cv2.so file but I have files for pip. In my /usr/local/lib/python2.7/ I only have a README

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790501/why-cv2-so-missing-after-opencv-installed

Comment: Another good resource is  http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/ (specifically geared towards Raspberry Pi, but still a Linux env)

Comment: EC2 uses yum, not apt-get, and some of the same dependencies aren't available in yum

Comment: Which OS did you choose when you launched your EC2 instance? CentOS? Any particular reason why you can't switch to a Debian platform?

Comment: What about this? http://techieroop.com/install-opencv-in-centos/

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html?highlight=download#installing-opencv-python-from-pre-built-binaries should help

Comment: @be_good_do_good I tried that but for some reason the cv2.so file can't be found. I tried to search for it using `sudo find / -name "cv2.so"`

Comment: @bblincoe I tried that but for some reason the cv2.so file can't be found. I tried to search for it using `sudo find / -name "cv2.so"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

tested and working on `amzn-ami-hvm-2016.03.1.x86_64-gp2`

```
sudo yum install git cmake gcc-c++ numpy python-devel 
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo ln -rs /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/18/eb/707897ab7c8ad15d0f3c53e971ed8dfb64897ece8d19c64c388f44895572/numpy-1.11.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
sudo pip install numpy-1.11.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl 
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 3.1.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DBUILD_opencv_python2=ON
make -j4
sudo make install
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/'>>~/.bashrc;. ~/.bashrc
python -c 'import cv2; print "cv2 imported"'
```

most importantly after cmake step. you should see this in the output.

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.10)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.10)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

now if it is not showing up, you need to completely remove build folder and rerun cmake again after correctly installing numpy, just rerunning cmake inside your already existing build folder will not work.

Comment: I ran the `cmake` command, and realized that `numpy` wasn't correctly installed. So I did `sudo yum uninstall numpy`. Then I tried installing `numpy-1.11.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`, but I got `numpy-1.11.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`

Comment: I've also updated my question with the output I get when running `cmake`

Comment: hmm..try the whl listed here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy. there's 4 for linux.

Comment: None of the four work. I keep getting this error: `numpy-1.11.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_i686.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: that's strange. what's the ami id of your instance?

Comment: This is what it says when I ssh into my instance: `https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2016.03-release-notes/`

Comment: did you upgrade pip? if it's not upgraded, you will get the platform error as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120729/discussion-between-shalin-shah-and-zaw-lin).

Comment: I opened a new instance because it just wasn't working on the old one. It worked on the new instance.

Comment: I was using a t2.nano and during `make -j4` I got `make: *** [all] Error 2` at about 40%. When I tried it on a t2.small which has more RAM everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

First create a virtual environment for python with the updated version of python because python2.7 is installed on it by default. Take help from the following link:-

### https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/python-boto3-virtualenv/

Then cd into the venv folder and execute the command :-

#### $ pip install opencv-python

Now run any script containing opencv by activating the virtual environment.

#### $ source /home/ec2-user/venv/python34/bin/activate

Done!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the command below and it worked:

```
cmake -D PYTHON2_LIBRARIES=/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 \
-D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/include/python2.7/ \
-D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/python \
-D HAVE_opencv_python2=ON ..
```