# Enable to run AWS beanstalk project with opencv

Tags: java, opencv, amazon-web-services, java-native-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting the error as shown below. Please suggest some link to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: [Check this link](http://arijitgeek.me/index.php/2016/06/24/install-opencv-3-1-0-with-python-2-7-on-aws-ubuntu-ec2-instance/)

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244606/how-to-install-opencv-on-amazon-linux) try this one also